# Trouble installing php-devel on CentOS 6

Tags: php, centos, yum

I'm trying to install the mongo drivers for PHP on CentosOS 6. Running "pecl install mongo" complains that "php-devel package is required".

Running "yum install php-devel" gives the following error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.usc.edu
 * epel: mirrors.xmission.com
 * extras: centos.sonn.com
 * updates: mirror.hmc.edu
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-devel.x86_64 0:5.3.3-14.el6_3 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php = 5.3.3-14.el6_3 for package: php-devel-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: automake for package: php-devel-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: autoconf for package: php-devel-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package autoconf.noarch 0:2.63-5.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package automake.noarch 0:1.11.1-1.2.el6 will be installed
---> Package php-devel.x86_64 0:5.3.3-14.el6_3 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php = 5.3.3-14.el6_3 for package: php-devel-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-devel-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: php = 5.3.3-14.el6_3
           Installed: php-5.3.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php = 5.3.15-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-5.3.3-3.el6_2.8.x86_64 (base)
               php = 5.3.3-3.el6_2.8
           Available: php-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
               php = 5.3.3-14.el6_3
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Any suggestions? It looks like it's trying to install devel for 5.3.3-14 rather than 5.3.3-15, but I'm not sure how to change that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `php-5.3.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64` was installed from the `remi` repo, but that repo is no longer available or enabled.

Try this first:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-devel
```

If you trust third-party repos, you should be able to enable it with these steps:

```
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm
sudo vim /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
    -> enabled=1
```

See http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-rhel-epel-repo-on-centos-5x-or-6x for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you upgraded PHP to 5.3.15 from the REMI repository

```
Installed: php-5.3.15-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
```

However, it looks like you have since removed the REMI repository from your yum repos, since I don't see any remi mirrors in the list there. Your currently enabled repos don't have the correct version of php-devel available. You'll need to re-add the REMI repository, and then install the php-devel version that matches your currently installed PHP version from there. In your case, you'll need php-devel-5.3.15.

Install Instructions for REMI:
http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en

Additional CentOS repos:
http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/